# Unresolved reference 'EC' is displaying while implementing WebdriverWait with python in pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pageobjects

I have created a BasePage class to implement POM in selenium with python. I have created a function to click on element as below:

```
def click(self, by_locator):
WebDriverWait(self.driver,10)
.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
.click()
```

Here EC is showing error:

> Unresolved reference 'EC'

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen on Internet I need to import expected conditions also with this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```